# 35mm Film through airport security

Tags: film, 35mm

I recently put some 35mm film in my checked luggage bag that I was taking on a trip. Basic Fuji Disposable Camera you can buy at Walmart/Target. I had not used them yet. I’ve been taking a bunch of photos with them this week and was wondering if I should be worried and if there is anything I can do to fix them if damaged. Didn’t know it was a bad idea until someone told me too late.